# rxjs-spy Value passed as error notification is not an Error instance =

Tags: rxjs

With [rxjs-spy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-spy), I have the following message in the browser console :

> Value passed as error notification is not an Error instance =

[image: example]

I am wondering if there is a way to locate the values producing these warnings to correct them directly with the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, they are warning to code from Angular library itself. For example the first one can be tracked to this line: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4648597d14e843f75c5e9dd761af740c1c27b5c0/packages/router/src/apply_redirects.ts#L31 where there is `NoMatch` object thrown that doesn't extend `Error`. So there is nothing you can do on your own. You can only ignore it.

Comment: Yes, it is what I figured it out when I tried with a new angular project with only rxjs-spy installed.